# String interpolation with variable from resource

Tags: c#, string, exception, resources, interpolation

I'm currently working on a .net 5.0 application.

I need to transform a Resource String with a variable into an exception message.

**Expected result:**
Fruit with Name: 'Apple' does not exist.

**Actual result:**
Fruit with Name: 'error' does not exist.

My **Resource string** in Translation.resx looks like this:

- Name: MyError
- Value: Fruit with name '{error}' does not exist.

My C# code to parse the message looks like this:

```
string formatter(string error) => $"{Translation.MyError}";

string message = formatter("Apple");

throw new Exception(message);
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Do you know how to transform a resource string with variable into an interpolated string?

Comment: You need to use `string.Format()`, not interpolated strings. So your resource string would become `Fruit with name '{0}' does not exist.` and your calling code would be `string.Format(Translation.MyError, error)`.

Comment: thanks, that's the only way to do it apparently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the [FormattableString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=net-5.0) class and the [FormattableStringFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.formattablestringfactory.create?view=net-5.0).
This is how to use them

```
string error = "Apple";

// This comes from your resourse.
string myErrorMessage =  "Fruit with name '{0}' does not exist.";
FormattableString s = FormattableStringFactory.Create(myErrorMessage, error);
string message = s.ToString();
```

However you still need to change your resources files to be as expected by the FormattableStringFactory. You need also to add the System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace to your project

Comment: Thanks! in my case it would even work without the FormattableStringFactory...

Comment: Like @Steve already mentioned, you still need to change your string to `"Fruit with name '{0}' does not exist"`. Since the `FormattableStringFactory` is really nothing more than a wrapper around `string.Format()` you might as well call `string.Format()` directly yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Another Possibility would be the NugetPackage 'ITVComponents.Formatting'.
In the class ITVComponents.Formatting.TextFormat there's an extension-method FormatText, which allows you to do something like this:

```cs
var tmp = new {error}.FormatText(Translation.MyError);
```

where Translation.MyError has the value "Fruit with name '[error]' does not exist."

The object you format can either be

- an object of any type. then public methods/properties/fields can be used
- an IDictionary<string,object>. then all items can be accessed by their name

Under the hood it uses a scripting-engine, so you can also use complex expressions such as

```
"'[error]' has [error.Length] letters, which is an [error.Length%2==0?\"\":\"un\"]-even number."
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll take a closer look at that one :)